# Error in converting file using python COM

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, com, comtypes

I have a very simple program which uses python `comtypes` module to convert `.doc` files to `.docx` files:

the code is:

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatDOCX = 16

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open("XYZ.doc")
doc.SaveAs("XYZ.docx", FileFormat=wdFormatDOCX)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

The input file is in same directory but it is always giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\py\newProj\parse.py", line 8, in <module>
    doc = word.Documents.Open("XYZ.doc")
COMError: (-2146823114, None, (u'Sorry, we couldn\u2019t find your file. Is it 
possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?\r (C:\\Windows\\system32\\XYZ.doc)',  
u'Microsoft Word', u'wdmain11.chm', 24654, None))
```

I do not know why it is searching for file in system directory even though I have give relative path.

The error persists even if I give absolute path.

So what is the problem here?

Comment: maybe permission issue. try to put the file to other place instead of system folder.

Comment: Agree with @JerryYYRain - don't ever use the `System` folder for anything like this. There is a reason the `Documents` folder exists... Jerry - why don't you write that as an answer; I suspect it may well be the solution.

Comment: @Floris That's the problem here, the error shows the directory of my python file and my doc file is in same folder.

Comment: @JerryYYRain the problem is that I din't use it.

Comment: Your Python file should also not be in the System folder...

Comment: @Floris it is not ,the error shows that the directory is F:\py\newProj\parse.py

Comment: Try to replace `doc = word.Documents.Open("XYZ.doc")` with `doc = word.Documents.Open("F:\\py\\newProj\\XYZ.doc")`... and similarly with the `saveas` command. Incidentally - is there a problem saving a `pdf` as a `docx`? That seems wrong...

Comment: try os.chdir(script_folder)

Comment: The current working directory is `C:\Windows\system32`. That's common when starting an elevated command prompt. Call `os.chdir(r'F:\py\newProj')`, or use an absolute path as @Floris suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The path needs to be escaped. You start Python in the environment that you are in or in the systems context. You can check this by goint to terminal and doing

```
import os
print(os.path)
```

To do this I used:

```
fulldocpath = os.getcwd() + "\\" + doc_file_name os.path.abspath(fulldocpath).replace('\\','\\\\\\\\')
doc = word.Documents.Add(osdocpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe you're gonna find it silly solution but it's actually worked and every thing is perfect

```
in_file = str(os.path.abspath("XYZ.docx").replace("c","C") # if the file path in c
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
```

it's actually silly that c small causing a problem in my case it was c small the problem cause when i replace it with C capital it worked (i mean the small c in the path not small c in general of course)